# Cannot find and delete the openjdk16

Tags: macos, java

I don't remember what action caused the system to use openjdk16 by default, I wanted to go back to jdk8 so I chose to delete openjdk16, but I don't see a folder for openjdk in the application/java/javaVirtualMachines folder on my computer, so I don't know where I can find it and delete it. Ignore the adoptopenjdk folder in the picture, that's me struggling..
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

check the java home path with command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

and change default java version:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```